# AOSP: What makes LineageOS Setup Wizard run in LockTask mode?

Tags: lineageos, aosp, kiosk-mode, setup-wizard

I have noticed that when you flash a device and run it for the first time you get into the setup wizard. I assume that application is being run in so called LockTask mode (Kiosk mode for dedicated devices) because it has only one navbar button (usually **"back"** button is the only displayed button, **"home"** and **"recents"** buttons are hidden).

Here are my questions:

1. Does setup wizard actually run in Kiosk mode? If yes, how to implement this? (I didn't find anything in LineageOS sources)
2. If no, what is the way of partially disabling navbar buttons?

Comment: This question has been cross-posted to [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77773900/150978). Have you tried to extract the setup wizard apk file from the device and decompile it to see if you can find how it works?

Comment: Please note that app development is off-topic since Android Enthusiasts focuses on end-users and power users (who are not necessarily developers) solving their issues. Thus, while this community might explain the technicality of Android OS to your queries, coding solutions are out of the scope of this community. For programming questions, [so] should be a more suitable site.